# How to ignore NA in subscripted assignment

Tags: arrays, r

Given two (named) arrays x and y, where all dimnames(y) exist in x.

How can I fill (update) x with values from y, but ignoring NAs in y?

I have come so far:

```
x<-array(1:15,dim=c(5,3),dimnames=list(1:5,1:3))
y<-(NA^!diag(1:3))*diag(1:3)
dimnames(y)<-list(1:3,1:3)
x[match(names(y[,1]),names(x[,1])),match(names(y[1,]),names(x[1,]))]<-y
```

But this also overwrites x with "NA"s from y.

```
   1  2  3
1  1 NA NA
2 NA  2 NA
3 NA NA  3
4  4  9 14
5  5 10 15
```

I guess it's something involving a filter !is.na(y) but I haven't found the right place to put it?

Thanks for any hint

Comment: I never realized `NA^0 == 1`; that's unexpected.

Comment: @A.Webb if you look at the [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/arithmetic.c) there are a number of checks within `R_pow` for special cases. The second is: `if(x == 1. || y == 0.) return(1.);`

Comment: Nevertheless, it is terribly inconsistent with the usual `NA` behavior where numerical computations with `NA` result in `NA`. I would personally avoid exploiting this edge case.

Comment: Agree on NA, it was only to create this illustrative example. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Webb I am responsible for giving that option in the OP's earlier post.   So , blame is on me :-). Though, I provided another solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `match` the rownames of 'y' with rownames of 'x' to create the row index ('rn'), similarly get the corresponding column index ('cn') by `match`ing.  Get the index of values in 'y' that are non-NAs ('indx').  Subset the 'x' with row index, column index and resubset with 'indx' and replace those values with the non-NA values in y (`y[indx]`).

```
 rn <- match(rownames(y), rownames(x))
 cn <- match(colnames(y), colnames(x))
 indx <- which(!is.na(y), arr.ind=TRUE)
 x[rn,cn][indx] <- y[indx]
```

Or instead of `match`ing, we can subset the 'x' with `rownames(y)` and `colnames(y)` and replace it as before.

```
 x[rownames(y), colnames(y)][indx] <- y[indx]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can index directly with `rownames` and `colnames` to get the relevant parts of x covered by y, and replace conditionally using `ifelse`:

```
x[rownames(y),colnames(y)] <- ifelse(is.na(y),x[rownames(y),colnames(y)],y)
x
  1  2  3
1 1  6 11
2 2  2 12
3 3  8  3
4 4  9 14
5 5 10 15
```

Answer (score 1):

just for completeness:
The accepted answer works under the assumption that we have a 2d-array (row/colnames).

But as the real problem was in higher dimension space (and this may the case for later readers) I show here how the solution can also be applied to the initial dimension-independent approach:

```
indx <- !is.na(y)
x[match(names(y[,1]),names(x[,1])),match(names(y[1,]),names(x[1,]))][indx] <- y[indx]
```

Thanks!